# How to describe a key sequence that starts with `C-u`?

Tags: key-bindings, help, prefix-argument, universal-argument

I am trying to use `C-h k` to describe the function to which a key is bound. But when I use it with a key chord like `C-u C-e C-x` it retrieves the documentation for `C-u` before I can finish typing the chord. What is the correct way to describe this type of chord?

Comment: Just don't type the `C-u`.

Comment: Prefix keys like `C-u` may be described in the function body. You should therefore ignore such prefix keys when using `C-h k` to describe a function.

Comment: @EmacsUser the function description of just `C-x C-e` did describe the usage of the prefix argument. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefix keys like C-u may be described in the function body. You should therefore ignore such prefix keys when using C-h k to describe a function.