# What function are associated with these expression evaluation commands in buffers?

Tags: key-bindings, help, prefix-argument

What are the function names for these two bindings?

`C-o C-x C-e` - evaluate expression before cursur and display limited length result in echo area

`C-u 0 C-x C-e` - evaluate expression before cursor and insert value at point.  The latter can also be expressed as `C-0 C-x C-e` but doesn't work in my configuration.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Description                                                                      | Key binding   | Function       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| evaluate expression before cursor and display in echo area                       | C-x C-e       |                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| evaluate expression before cursor and insert limited length result at point      | C-j           | eval-last-sexp |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| evaluate expression before cursor and display limited length result in echo area | C-o C-x C-e   |                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| evaluate expression before cursor and insert value at point                      | C-u 0 C-x C-e |                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Trying to check them via the descbinds function doesn't seem to work well.

Is there some formal way of  expressing key bindings as strings that can be used to lookup their matching functions?

Comment: 1. Did you mean `C-o C-x C-e` or `C-0 C-x C-e`? `C-o` is itself bound to command `open-line`, which inserts a newline character. 2. What is "the descbinds function" - do you mean `C-h k`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to describe a key sequence that starts with \`C-u\`?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22709/how-to-describe-a-key-sequence-that-starts-with-c-u)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only relevant key-binding to search is: `C-x C-e` which for me is bound to `eval-last-sexp`. `C-0` and `C-u 0` are prefix args that are passed to the function that `C-x C-e` is bound to; they don't change the function that is run.

To see what `C-x C-e` is bound to, type `C-h k C-x C-e`.

You can use this command to

```
(describe-key "\C-x\C-e")
(describe-key (kbd "C-x C-e"))
```

You can get a list of all the currently accessible bindings with `M-x describe-bindings`. Then you can search for a string in it.

Comment: I have updated the question with a cheat sheet table that I am creating. What I am looking for are the associated function names if there are any.

Comment: I am hoping to find a tool that will allow me to make the tables cells multiline to prevent it from being too wide.

Comment: I think you missed the point. all your empty function cells point to the same function: whatever C-x C-x points to. all the things before those are just prefix args that get passed to that command. Also, as @Drew pointed out in your third cell down it should be C-0 C-x C-e.